# Double free or corruption error

Tags: c

I keep getting this error:

```
*** glibc detected *** /s/httpget: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00000000005352a0 ***
```

I don't really see, that I do free twice. So I guess it because of coruption...
I did some comments in the attached code, so please have a look there, to understand the problem better.

```
Here backtrace:
#5  0x0000000000401077 in processXML (
    start=0x506010 "<I k=\"506012,148,1\" b=\"158\" n=\"11393\" \n</I>\n<I k=\"2553367,257,814\" b=\"2781\" n=\"43020\"                                                                                    "1\" td=\"15\" d=\"20131204\" t=\"144734\" z=\"110\">\n<P k=\"33,3,0\" gn=\"1\" v=\"18.65\"/>\n<P k=\"33,3,1\" v=\"18.65                                                                                   >\n</I>\n<I "..., stop=0x50af1a "<I k=\"506012,148,1\" b=\"158\" n=\"11393\" ", t=0x51ecb0) at cli.c:178
#6  0x0000000000401669 in main () at cli.c:292
```

Here the code:

```
void processXML(char *start, char *stop, GTree* t)
{
    if (start == NULL)return;
    start = strstr(start,START);
    char *  cp = start ;
    char * tmpP;
    gpointer* key;
    ticP tP;
    size_t  symlen=0;
    while (cp < stop)
    {
      //here the first occurance of the var, which causes the problem
      char * triP;
      cp  =  (strchr( cp, '"'))+1;
      tmpP = strchr( cp, '"');
      if ( tmpP != NULL )
      {
        symlen  = (tmpP - cp) ;
        printf("mallocated %zu\n", symlen) ;
        //EDIT
        triP = malloc(symlen+1);
        memcpy (triP, tmpP - (symlen) , symlen);
        triP [symlen]   = '\0';
        printf(">>VAL %s<<\n", triP);
        cp = strstr( cp, STARTP);
        if (cp == NULL){ return;}
      }
     if (triP != NULL && (key = g_tree_lookup (t, triP))== NULL )
     {
        printf("I N S E R T E D \n");
        tP = malloc(sizeof(tic));
        g_tree_insert(t, triP, tP);
     }
     //here I try to free it but only if some bytes were allocated...   
     if (symlen >0)free (triP);
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Definitely corruption, yes. This:

```
triP = malloc(symlen);
memcpy (triP, tmpP - (symlen) , symlen);
triP [symlen]   = '\0';
```

is clobbering into non-allocated space with the final line. If you allocate `symlen` bytes, valid indices are from 0 up to (and including) `symlen - 1`, but the index `symlen` is 1 byte beyond the allocated space. Boom.

As usual, to build a string holding `n` actual visible characters, you need `n + 1` characters' worth of space, to include the terminator.